# Javascript: Get what character and where from key press

Tags: javascript, html, keypress

I'm trying to get the exact input change (what character and where) which comes from key press to an input field in HTML5 but I can't figure out how to do it "nicely".

My findings so far:

Event `oninput(event)` is too high-level, it basically says: "something" has changes. I don't know where and what exactly. Comparison of the original and current values sounds heavy for a big string.
Event `onkeypress(event)` is too low-level it does not care about where `event.which` goes into the input field.

Is there a way to get both what character user typed and where exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a broad question, but I'll try to answer anyways. You can listen to  onkeydown event and know what key has been pressed.

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
      alert(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) + " was pressed");
   }
};
```

After that you can get the position of where the key has been pressed.

```
var cursorPosition = $('#myTextarea').prop("selectionStart");
```

What you want to do with this basic information is up to you! You can build a little more intelligent code on top of this. Good luck!